# Android - сигнатуры приложения не совпадают

Tags: android, eclipse

Столкнулся с неприятным фактом при подписывании приложения одним и тем же ключом. В феврале подписал приложение, залил на Google Play, установил на свой смартфон. На днях обновил код, загрузил на смартфона напрямую - "сигнатуры не совпадают".
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Напрямую это `RUN/DEBUG`? Или сделали signed APK, закинули в телефон и из его файл-менеджера запустили установку?

Comment: может вместо релиз версии дебаг собрали или наоборот

Comment: @woesss, сделал signed APK, закинул в телефон и установил. Так понимаю, так не делается?

Comment: Не-не - как раз в таком случае сигнатуры должны были совпасть. То есть если  Вы сделали APK так же, как и для магазина и подписали тем же ключом.

Comment: Уверены что ключ тот же? Что Вы не перепутали с другим, что не создали новый с такими же данными, а именно достали из keystore-файла, где-то у Вас хранившегося всё это время?

Comment: @woesss, уверен, ключ тот же, да и Eclipse автоматически то же самое хранилище "подсунул", которое использовалось полгода назад. Попробую Гугл Плею скормить "новую" версию подписанного этим ключом приложения.